# Как в данном случае лучше использовать replaceAll?

Tags: java

```
String jparse = [[10, 20, 'stringone', '{gvdfdf}'], [12, 30, 'stringtwo', '{vxcbnn}']]
```

как сделать replace all, что бы осталось [{gvdfdf}, {vxcbnn}]

Comment: омг. Мне кажется, раз возник такой вопрос вот с такими входными данными, то Вы где-то ранее свернули не туда. Откуда берутся такие данные?

Comment: Спасибо за "развёрнутый" ответ.

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий с вопросом о том, откуда Вы получаете эти данные. Если можно сделать так, чтобы данные поступали в более удобном формате, то будет проще парсить. Я ожидал, что Вы приложите дополнительную информацию или код, где генерируется такая строка и с какой целью.

Comment: Ну Ок, данные приходят с БД(Tarantool), формат данных изменить не представляется возможным.

Comment: Это очень похоже на JSON массив, я бы спарсил эту строку в массив массивов и работал с ним.

Comment: Да, верно, а примерный вариант реализации не подскажите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наконец-то у меня получилось:

```
String jparse = "[[10, 20, 'stringone', '{gvdfdf}'], [12, 30, 'stringtwo', '{vxcbnn}']]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\w*}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jparse);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (sb.length() == 0) {
        sb.append("[");
    } else {
        sb.append(",");
    }
    sb.append(matcher.group(0));
}
sb.append("]");

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Получаем: *[{gvdfdf},{vxcbnn}]*

`\w` в выражении говорит о том, что нужно искать все буквы, цифры и знак _

Знак `*` говорит о том, что символов может быть любое количество (включая 0). Если хотите чтобы отбрасывались пустые фигурные скобки, то замените на `+`.

Фигурные скобки, обрамляющие выражение, показывают что символы, соответствующие `\w` должны быть между фигурных скобок.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!